# Lock wait timeout exceeded when calling pymysql executemany after disconnection

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a reasonably large dataset of about 6,000,000 rows X 60 columns that I am trying to insert into a database.  I am chunking them, and inserting them 10,000 at a time into a mysql database using a class I've written and pymysql.  The problem is, I occasionally time out the server when writing, so I've modified my executemany call to re-connect on errors.  This works fine for when I lose connection once, but if I lose the error a second time, I get a pymysql.InternalException stating that lock wait timeout exceeded.  I was wondering how I could modify the following code to catch that and destroy the transaction completely before attempting again.

I've tried calling rollback() on the connection, but this causes another InternalException if the connection is destroyed because there is no cursor anymore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I also don't understand why I am getting the timeouts to begin with, but the data is relatively large.)

```py
class Database:
    def __init__(self, **creds):
        self.conn = None
        self.user = creds['user']
        self.password = creds['password']
        self.host = creds['host']
        self.port = creds['port']
        self.database = creds['database']

    def connect(self, type=None):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(
            host = self.host,
            user = self.user,
            password = self.password,
            port = self.port,
            database = self.database
        )

    def executemany(self, sql, data):
        while True:
            try:
                with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.executemany(sql, data)
                    self.conn.commit()
                    break

            except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
                print('Connection error.  Reconnecting to database.')
                time.sleep(2)
                self.connect()
                continue

        return cursor
```

and I am calling it like this:

```py
for index, chunk in enumerate(dataframe_chunker(df), start=1):
     print(f"Writing chunk\t{index}\t{timer():.2f}")
     db.executemany(insert_query, chunk.values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what MySQL is doing.  The lockwait timeouts are because the inserts cannot be done until something else finishes, which could be your own code.

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`innodb_locks`;
```

Will show the current locks.

```
select * from information_schema.innodb_trx where trx_id = [lock_trx_id];
```

Will show the involved transactions

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST where id = [trx_mysql_thread_id];
```

Will show the involved connection and may show the query whose lock results in the lock wait timeout. Maybe there is an uncommitted transaction.

It is likely your own code, because of the interaction with your `executemany` function which catches exceptions and reconnects to the database.  What of the prior connection?  Does the lockwait timeout kill the prior connection?  That while true is going to be trouble.

For the code calling `executemany` on the db connection, be more defensive on the try/except with  something like:

```
    def executemany(self, sql, data):
        while True:
            try:
                with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
                    cursor.executemany(sql, data)
                    self.conn.commit()
                    break
            except pymysql.err.OperationalError:
                print('Connection error.  Reconnecting to database.')
                if self.conn.is_connected():
                    connection.close()
            finally:
                time.sleep(2)
                self.connect()
```

But the solution here will be to not induce lockwait timeouts if there are no other database clients.

Comment: I figured it was my own code, but I am not entirely sure how I would kill the connection if I get the first initial timeout error that necessitates trying the connection again.  Also, the information_schema section is empty -- is that something I would need to set up?

Comment: You need to look at the locks while your code is running and timing out.  It is tricky to do, but that is where you will see the locks.   I've updated the answer to include closing the connection before retrying.

Comment: In the information_schema table, the lock_timeouts are set to a max of two, so if the script fails once but then reconnects and runs through, there is no problem, but the second failure will cause the timeout_lock error.  Is there a danger in upping that lock timeout limit if this data store will be consumed by a viz software later?  The dump process is just a nightly thing, but daily there may be hundreds/thousands of people pulling from a location that is fed by this data.

Comment: `show PROCESSLIST; ` may also be of use while troubleshooting. For remaining points on many readers/one-writer, that is a database architecture thing best addressed by a DBA type of person.

Comment: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST shows two rows if it reconnects twice, so it's definitely not killing the transaction as I've currently written it.  A few quick questions, 1.  you have that if in the except block wrapped in parenthesis.  Any reason for this?  2. I'd want to call close() on self.conn, not connection, right?  3. would it be best to test if the connection is open, call conn.rollback(), then conn.close() to properly close the connection and create a new conn?  4. is there any overhead creating a new conn object for every transaction like this if I'm making ~600 writes to the database?